# How to build cloud function with different environment like testing/development?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, development-environment

The cloud function should display bucketname on different environment like testing and production

Based on the Firebase [a doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) I have set config

### runtimeconfig.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "environment": "testing"
  }
}
```

The config file does not have environment `production` because I am not sure how the structure should be like for switch from `testing` to `production`

### index.ts

```
exports.bucketName = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const bucketName = functions.config().project.environment;
    res.send(bucketName);
});
```

The bucketname should dynamically changed based on the environment.

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build-and-watch": "tsc -w",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell"    
  }
}
```

Can someone suggest whats the best way to switch environment for Cloud Function?

For example a command like `npm run build --configuration=test` which loads the testing environment likewise for dev `npm build --configuration=dev` for dev environment.

Comment: The standard practice is to have a different project for each development environment.  The documentation you linked to talks about setting the configuration for the project before deployment. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#set_environment_configuration_for_your_project

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I found that doc which helped me to set the config. But if I deploy how will the environment change to `production` that's the part I am confused with.

Comment: Update the configuration before you deploy.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I think that's the best way to switch. using set command based on the environment. Thanks, Mate I guess I was overthinking.

Comment: @RahulThawal, I am just curious, updating the environment, won't it overwrite, will there be an option to use test env as well as prod env at once

Answer (score 0):

As @Doug Stevenson suggested set the config based on what environment should do the job. I am using the firebase set and then deploy.